# Monkey Talk Android

Tags: monkeytalk

I am working on monkey Talk Android agent , I successfully recorded login page but when ever I am navigating to the Calender screen within the app , it is crashing . Can anyone please help me out with a solution

Comment: Can you please post a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's because when we try to navigate to calendar at that time the same event is triggered twice that what i know when i do debug with my developer and i guess this is a issue from Gorilla logic and hope they will fix it on there next release.